# How to implement a static counter in python

Tags: python, static

I am calling a method and I need a static counter within this method. It's required to parse the elements of the list. The counter will tell which position of the list to lookup at.

For e.g

```
static_var_with_position = 0
noib_list = [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2]

def foo(orig_output, NOB):
    # tried two ways

    #static_var_with_position += 1 # doesn't work

    #global static_var_with_position
    #static_var_with_position += 1 # doesn't work either

    bit_required = noib_list[static_var_with_position]
    converted_output = convert_output(orig_output, NOB, bit_required)
```

The static_var_with_position value is never incremented. I have commented the two ways I tried to increment value.

In c++ its piece of cake, but I couldn't find anything similar in python so far. Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: can you paste some code you tried... will surely figure it out something

Comment: I have updated the ques, hope it makes it a bit clear

Comment: Have you considered using an `iterator` instead?

Comment: the second global statement should work. What's the error you are getting if you uncomment those two lines

Comment: @JayParikh I dont get any error, but the value never increments. I ran debug and its always 0.

Comment: @tobias_k no, I havent used iterator. you mean to use enumerate?

Comment: can you not add `static_var_with_position` to the `return`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a global/static counter variable, you could use an [`iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#iter):

```
iterator = iter(noib_list)

def foo(orig_output, NOB):
    bit_required = next(iterator)
    converted_output = convert_output(orig_output, NOB, bit_required)
```

The iterator will automatically keep track which is the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#next) element internally.

When the iterator is exhausted (i.e. when you reached the end of the list), `next` will raise a `StopIteration` error, so it you do not know when the end is reached, you can use `bit_required = next(iterator, None)` instead; then just test whether the value is `None` and you know that the list is exhausted (or just use `try/except`).

Answer (score 1):

Following this example, you could do the same with your counter :

```
def inc() : 
    global global_cpt 
    global_cpt +=1
    print global_cpt

if __name__ == '__main__' : 
    global_cpt = 0
    inc()
    inc()
    inc()
```

will print

```
> 1
> 2
> 3
```

Comment: Thanks. It works if I run it, but when I include the same in my project I get following error  `static_var_with_position+=1
NameError: name static_var_with_position' is not defined` The file with main method invokes `foo(orig_output, NOB)` which internally calls inc() `bit_required = noib_list[inc()]`

Comment: Note that if the `+=` line is before the line that gets the value from the list, it will skip the first value.

Comment: @tobias_k you are right, it was the case. Thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually advocate doing this in your case, but it's a little-known hack for creating a "static" variable within a function: put it as a parameter with a mutable default value! You can modify it within the function and it will hold until the next function call, as long as the caller doesn't pass a value for it.

```
def foo(value=[0]):
    value[0] += 1
    print(value[0])

>>> foo()
1
>>> foo()
2
>>> foo()
3
>>> foo([906])
907
>>> foo()
4
```

Comment: Thanks. I am curious "I don't actually advocate doing this in your case". Since I am new to python, would like to know the possible disadvantage or situations where using static like thing isnt a good idea in pyhton

Comment: @blackbug anything that's likely to confuse people should be discouraged. Using a parameter as something other than a parameter is definitely confusing. As to your original problem, globals are considered a bad idea in all languages because they're a nearly invisible form of coupling. At least my solution keeps it local to the function.